# Joomla 3.1 Tags not works

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I have upgraded from joomla 3.0.2 to Joomla 3.1, I want to use Tags but does not work.

[image]

No Error shows

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to the update manager and make sure that your database is up to date. Also, what exactly were you trying to do when you got that error?

Comment: Database is up to date.I got this error when I tagged artical and push save button

Comment: I would update to the current release since it's very hard to know what could be happening in an out of date codebase.